# Не удается подключить mysql к python 3.X

Tags: mysql, python, django

Пытаюсь подключить mysql к python, пробую через mysql-connector-python

Пробую установить через  `sudo pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python`
Получаю следующее :

```
Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
pip install pymysql
```

В `__init__.py` :

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Answer (score 0):

В `requirements.txt`

измените `mysql-connector-python==ваша_версия`

на(например):

```
https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.0.12.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Необходимо установить adodbapi и pandas**

```
pip install pandas

pip install adodbapi
```

**2. Выполнить подключение**

```
import pandas as pd
import adodbapi
```

**3. Основной код**

```
constr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=your_password;User_ID=your_user;Initial_Catalog=Name_BD;Data_Source=host,port"
```

*your_passord* - пароль от вашей БД

*User_ID* - Логин вашей БД

*Initial_Catalog* - Наименование вашей БД

*Data_Source* - например 10.111.222.333,1432

```
conn = adodbapi.connect(constr)
```

Произвели подключение

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM db"
```

Записали sql запрос в нашу бд

```
data = pd.read_sql(sql, con=conn)
```

И далее делаем махинации с нашими данными. Формат возвращаемого значения: DataFrame.